# Outputting default value when record not found

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure-sql-database

I am selecting 4 different columns each in their own respective table. ProductID, ProductDesc, TransactionDate and TransactionPrice.

When using the below query as an example where records exist:

```
SELECT transactionProducts.productID, products.productDesc, transactionDate, transactionProducts.price 
FROM transactionProducts INNER JOIN transactions ON transactionProducts.transactionID = transactions.transactionID 
INNER JOIN products on products.productID=transactionProducts.productID 
WHERE (transactionProducts.productID='1011021' AND transactions.transactionDate='2017-01-07')
GROUP BY transactionProducts.productID, products.productDesc, transactionDate, transactionProducts.price  
ORDER BY transactionDate
```

the output is as follows

```
ProductID  | Product Desc | TransactionDate | TransactionPrice
1011021    | SD DOG       | 2017-01-07      | $15
```

My goal is to return a record even if a productID (e.g. 1011021) isnt associated to a transactionDate. The following query queries for a date that doesnt exist

```
SELECT transactionProducts.productID, products.productDesc, transactionDate, transactionProducts.price  
FROM transactionProducts INNER JOIN transactions ON transactionProducts.transactionID = transactions.transactionID 
INNER JOIN products on products.productID=transactionProducts.productID 
WHERE (transactionProducts.productID='1011021' AND transactions.transactionDate='2017-01-18')
GROUP BY transactionProducts.productID, products.productDesc, transactionDate, 
ORDER BY transactionDate
```

The current output I would get would be (no records found):

```
ProductID  | Product Desc | TransactionDate | TransactionPrice
           |              |                 |
```

The output I am looking for would still output the productID productDesc and transactionDate that was specified in the query but return the transactionPrice as 0.

```
ProductID  | Product Desc | TransactionDate | TransactionPrice
1011021    | SD DOG       | 2017-01-18      | 0
```

I want to force the transactionPrice to be set to 0 if a transaction for the given ProductID (1011021) didn't take place on the given TransactionDate (2017-01-08), any other suggestions as how to achieve this?

Comment: Well if there isn't a transaction why would there be a transaction date? If you are trying to force a transaction of 0 amount for every date in a range then you need to state that in the question.

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do and I have now stated it in the question, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Yep. Use a function to populate a temp table of dates in the your range and full join to it. There are a lot of examples on this. Look up calendar tables. Someone will likely give you a solution though. Cheers!

Comment: Mind sharing any of those examples?

Comment: I'm on my mobile so it's hard to code it for you

Comment: Ok whenever you can would be great please and thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER` and
2. Allow `NULL`'s for `transactions.transactionDate` and `transactionProducts.productID` in the `WHERE` clause so that they should up when they have no corresponding records in the other tables.
3. Since you want all Products even if there are no transactions, that should be the `FROM` clause followed by `LEFT JOIN`'s.
4. Additionally, if you want `transactionProducts.price` to show as `0` instead of `NULL`, change that in the `SELECT` to `ISNULL(transactionProducts.price, 0)`.

That way, (a) all products show up in even if there's no transaction and (b) the `WHERE` clause on `transactionDate` doesn't exclude missing records:

```
SELECT transactionProducts.productID, products.productDesc, transactionDate, ISNULL(transactionProducts.price, 0)
FROM products
LEFT JOIN transactionProducts on products.productID = transactionProducts.productID
LEFT JOIN transactions ON transactionProducts.transactionID = transactions.transactionID
WHERE (transactionProducts.productID = '1011021' OR transactionProducts.productID IS NULL)
      AND
      (transactions.transactionDate = '2017-01-18' OR transactions.transactionDate IS NULL)
GROUP BY transactionProducts.productID, products.productDesc, transactionDate
ORDER BY transactionDate
```

(*Note: `transactionDate` will still show as `NULL` if there aren't any transactions for that product on that date. So if you want to show some other default date instead, apply `ISNULL()` to that too.)*